# Application of class equation

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

The class equation is defined on finite group $G$ with $a\in G$, then

$|G|=\sum_{s}|G:C(a)|$ where $s$: sum runs over elements from distinct conjugacy classes. 
My question what are the applications of this class equation ??

Answer (score 0):

One of the application is to prove the following result:

> The center of any finite $p$-group is non-trivial.